# Add clickable link to XpsDocument

Tags: hyperlink, xpsdocument

How can I add a clickable link to XpsDocument?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

XPS supports links, both to locations within the document, as to URLs.

Not sure there's an API in .NET for it, but ours (http://nixps.com) supports it.

Comment: This is clear. I meant some code examples of adding, as links disappear on converting flow doc to xps document